# Image and Title not shown on navigation bar back button at time

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

how to create back button with both image and title in navigation bar.below is my code,In which both image and title not seen at time on button,how to achieve this. please suggest me.

```
 UIButton *nav_BackButton1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,10 ,60, 24)];
    nav_BackButton1.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    nav_BackButton1.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
    [nav_BackButton1 setTitle:@"Ik" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nav_BackButton1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nav_BackButton1 setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,30, 0, 0)];
    [nav_BackButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_bar_up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nav_BackButton1 setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 35)];
    [nav_BackButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(backTOChoiceScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:nav_BackButton1];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backBarBtn;
```

Comment: nav_BackButton1 setBackgroundImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method `setBackgroundImage:forState:` instead of `setImage:forState:` for setting background image to `nav_BackButton1`.

Comment: but, this image not moved to left side in button.

Answer (score 0):

try changing;

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarBtn;
```

with:

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarBtn;
```